# Ignoring part of the query string when routing in ASP.NET Web Api

Tags: routes, authorization, asp.net-web-api

I'm using an appKey query string parameter to authorise some client applications.

Example request: **myserver/mydata?appKey=12345**

I have a DelegatingHandler that validates the appKey, so I do not need it later when I'm actually serving the request. However, even though I do not need it, I need to add it my method signature like the following, else NotFound will be returned.

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetMyData(string appKey)
```

Is there a way to use the following method to handle the request, even though the query string has the appKey paremeter?

```
public HttpResponseMessage GetMyData()
```

Comment: Not so clear. Do you mean something like `public HttpResponseMessage GetMyData(string appKey = null)` ?

Comment: No. I mean that I want to have exactly the following:
public HttpResponseMessage GetMyData()

Comment: Its much confusing, please be more specific, what exact URL you want and what method signature should be...

Comment: Sorry guys! I want this method `public HttpResponseMessage GetMyData()` (it has no arguments) to handle this request **myserver/mydata?appKey=12345** (there is a querystring parameter) after the querystring has been handled by a delegate handler. By default it doesn't work since the default routing tries to bind the querystring param into a method argument.

In the meantime I found one solution. While still in the message handler code, I can change the Message.RequestUri and remove the query string part. In this case routing mechanism can route the call to the method I want!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the meantime I found one solution. While still in the message handler code, I can change the Message.RequestUri and remove the query string part. In this case routing mechanism can route the call to the method I want.

So the request can be this **myserver/mydata?appKey=12345** but the code that handles it can be the following (no sign of appKey there)

```
[Route]
public HttpResponseMessage GetMyData()
```

Answer (score 1):

I still don't catch the reason for this.

Anyhow: have you tried with the routing attributes? Something similar to:

```
[Route("myserver/mydata?appKey={key}")]
[HttpPost]
public public HttpResponseMessage GetMyData() { ... }
```

I did not test it, but thanks to te Route attribute is'd be called with your URL. Try it.

Further info here:

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2

Comment: The reason is that the appKey in the query string is handled by the authorisation layer of my application (a delegate handler in particular). I don't want this to be part of the actual handling of the request (i.t. the controller and its methods). This is not how web api routing works by default. If something is in the query string, so I was looking for a solution. The one I found, like I say about, is to change the Message.RequestUri and remove the appKey from the query string, while still in the delegate handler.